# EmberJs outlet inside multiple nested route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I do not strictly understand outlets and rendering templates in EmberJS. Until now I have been doing mostly CRUD operations or my routes weren't nested as many times as here so I haven't faced this problem yet.
Using `{{outlet}}` in parent route was enough.

The problem comes with my approach that I used to. 
Everything works fine when I do visit `routes admin/*`, but when I try to get into e.g. `admin/organization/{id}/user` it renders an `admin/organization` template what I would want to avoid. 
I suppose these things can be done using `renderTemplate(`) function inside `route.js` but I can't figure these things out.

I recreated my routes structure in [[twiddle]](https://ember-twiddle.com/5c4ef7ba1225ac3e85ac2d457af7ff48)

Could someone explain to me that, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested routes always have nested templates. To workaround, you can utilize `index` route, which exists on every level by default. Structure of your templates will be like this:

```
-app
--templates
---admin
----organization
-----index.hbs //template for admin/organization/index route, url: /admin/organization
-----user.hbs //template for admin/organization/user route, url: /admin/organization/user
----index.hbs //template for admin/index route, url: /admin
```

Note that if some template file does not exist (in my example `app/templates/admin.hbs`, `app/templates/admin/organization.hbs` do not exist), it's the same as having `.hbs` file with only `{{outlet}}` in it